# Как вывести массив json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Получаю такой ответ после json_encode:

```
[{"server_id":"10","server_ip":"193.26.217.73","server_port":"27042"},{"server_id":"9","server_ip":"46.174.52.26","server_port":"27246"},{"server_id":"11","server_ip":"37.230.228.226","server_port":"10000"}]
```

как вывести это на страницу?

Comment: Куда вывести, в каком виде?

Comment: @Alexxosipov Хотябы так `console.log(server_id);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{
    "server_id": "10",
    "server_ip": "193.26.217.73",
    "server_port": "27042"
  },
  {
    "server_id": "9",
    "server_ip": "46.174.52.26",
    "server_port": "27246"
  },
  {
    "server_id": "11",
    "server_ip": "37.230.228.226",
    "server_port": "10000"
  }
];

for (var key in data) {
  var item = data[key];
  console.log(item.server_id);
}
```

Comment: А вот это уже другой разговор, ведь можно было и сразу так ответить :))) У меня однако и была такая мысля но она потерялась так как не работало, как я дошел до `i++` сам не заметил. вот эта точка перед server_id меня очень смущает и сейчас. Такое чувство что ее там не должно быть. Но на практике совсем другое.

Comment: а теперь точка между `item` и `server_id` не смущает?

Comment: Согласен, плохо мне дается синтаксис. В PHP я лучше понимаю, ну что ж. Будем учить :)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
var i=0;
for (key in data) {
    console.log(data[i].server_id);
    i++;
}
```

И пошел делать дальше, а вы можете дальше продолжать ставить "-".
P.S. Да, я плохо знаю js. Но я учусь, и не тыкаю минусы.

Comment: Вам поставили минус (да, это был я) не за то, что Вы плохо знаете javascript, а за то, как Вы задали вопрос. `for (key in data) { console.log(data[k].server_id); }`

Comment: @Igor я сам задал, и сам ответил. И мой ответ меня полностью устраивает. Если бы нужно было бы что то еще я бы добавил к вопросу. А ответил для того что бы возможно кто то еще варианты предложит.

Comment: Все это очень здорово, пока Вы задаете вопросы сами себе. Но Ваш-то вопрос предназначался другим. Обратите внимание на то, что переменная `i` в Вашем коде не нужна.

Comment: @Igor если бы я видел такой вопрос и знал бы ответ, то я бы ответил и...Закончим на эту тему. А вот если без `i` хотел бы я видеть пример.

Comment: @Igor Да я смотрел, но там вот такое: `service.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: k is not defined
    at Object.success (service.js:24)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4) ` я не думаю же что вы вместо `i` предложили написать `k`

Comment: Это хорошо, что вы самостоятельно учитесь, но всё-таки вам правильно указывают на то, что вы не очень понятно излагаете свои мысли. Вопрос изложен непонятно. Может быть вам нужно красивую табличку нарисовать? И если ваш ответ вас устраивает - то вы не видите возможность улучшить код и подняться на более высокий уровень программирования. Постарайтесь не обижаться, а увидеть во всём этом рациональное зерно.